# How to use correct regional format (date & time) of Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: localization, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

In WP8.1 region settings, one can set a country/region and a regional format. In my case I have United States as the country/region and German (Germany) as the regional format because of Cortana.

However, the time picker as well as the date picker use 12hrs AM/PM format and the US date format mm-dd-yyyy.

I can't find any property which tells me the regional format that's visible in the settings dialog of WP8.1.

Is there any localization/globalization feature of Windows Phone Store apps, that I am missing? How can I get the exact time/date output that's printed in the region settings dialog in my own app, without letting the user select the date/time format itself again?

Comment: Can anyone confirm that MS didn't fix this after almost 2 years as it may be a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560412/winrt-apps-and-regional-settings-the-correct-way-to-format-dates-and-numbers-ba ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.aspx) namespace on how to get specific formatting date masks.

Also, take a look at the Windows.Globalization(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.aspx) namespace

Comment: That's exactly where I've been looking. However, everywhere there is only English (US) stuff, nothing German. No €, no dd.mm.yyyy and no 24 hour clock, as it should return because of my current regional format.